# How to change firebase realtime database URL in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tsx

How can i change database url (firebase real time db) in code? I would like to have option to choose which database you want (just different links)

I have firebaseConfig.ts file where is my firebaseconfig variable that contains apikey, authDomain, databaseURL, ...

Comment: If you have that config, you can change the `databaseURL` property in there to point to the database you want. Did it not work when you tried that? If so, can you show what you did and what error you got?

Comment: It worked that way, but i want to be able to change db e.g. based on button clicked. Answer below helped me and thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#web

You can have multiple firebase configs in an object
like

```js
var configs = {"option1":{},"option2":{}}
```

and then initialise them all with different names like

```
var databases = {}
Object.keys(configs).map((name)=>{
  const app = firebase.initializeApp(configs[name],name);
  databases[name]=app;
})
```

then based on the choice you can access the database and access the db and change the values etc

```
const app = databases["option1"]
//access the realtime db and so on
```